# Running Twisted on Azure Websites

Tags: twisted, azure-web-app-service, twisted.web

Can Azure Websites host Twisted applications? e.g. something like:

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import server

site = server.Site(myresource)
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)
reactor.run()
```

From http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/ it sounds like only WSGI apps are supported, but just wanted to confirm from an Azure Websites expert that there's no way to directly run something like the above.

--

This excerpt from discussion with Glyph (Twisted author) in the #twisted.web IRC channel covers the Twisted half of this question:

```
16:53:28 glyph: twisted has a WSGI _container_
16:53:34 glyph: twisted _is not_ a WSGI application
16:53:36 glyph: in any part
16:53:43 glyph: so you can't make twisted into a WSGI app
16:53:55 glyph: you can maybe invoke some Twisted code _from_ a WSGI app
16:54:05 glyph: but what that example is doing is speaking HTTP, and WSGI applications have to speak WSGI, they are not allowed to speak HTTP directly.
16:56:47 tos9: crochet?
16:56:56 glyph: tos9: crochet can't eat the inbound HTTP socket
16:56:58 glyph: tos9: so it doesn't help
16:57:11 glyph: you could write a thing that did the _outgoing_ traffic with Twisted, but since you can't handle the inbound request, you're bummed
16:57:37 glyph: basically Twisted's job is doing network I/O and if you're inside a WSGI stack, someone else is already doing the job of doing the network I/O
```

If there is in fact no way to directly run something like this, it seems like choosing a language other than Python buys you more flexibility on Azure Websites. For example, from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/ it looks like you can host a Node app on Azure Websites which speaks HTTP directly. Confirmations or corrections gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed1c80c4-4621-4d02-8902-6ecc1166ac8c/running-twisted-on-azure-websites?forum=windowsazurewebsitesprevie&prof=required for answer.

As you described in  [Running Twisted on Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620060/running-twisted-on-azure-websites) .

What you said is right. For node.js, you can host a Node app on Azure Websites which speaks HTTP directly. Please refer to  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2012/05/05/top-benefits-of-running-node-js-on-windows-azure.aspx

For Python, there's no direct way run twiisted code via http.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Just replied in the MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed1c80c4-4621-4d02-8902-6ecc1166ac8c/running-twisted-on-azure-websites#421ac1a3-47f9-4350-8f01-4f2d41cd79a9 -- further discussion can move there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.  Their [main page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-azure/) says

> Azure supports any operating system, language, tool, and framework— from Windows to Linux, SQL Server to Oracle, C# to Java.

The page you referenced shows a basic template - it is an example of how to set up a particular WSGI application.  You don't have to do it this way.

You can setup a virtual machine and put anything you like on it.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about Azure Websites, not Azure Virtual Machines. Azure Websites specifically does not support any OS, language, tool, etc. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure_Web_Sites#Implementation: "Microsoft Azure Web Sites is implemented as websites that are dynamically created on-demand on servers running Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.0."

Comment: Yes, I guess that's right. If you want to use Twisted on Azure, use an Azure Virtual Machine (e.g. from a Linux or *BSD image will do and works fine).

Answer (score -1):

If Twisted doesn't require any specific binaries to be installed (no registry keys, hard coded path requirements, etc) then you can just copy the relevant binaries over with your website and invoke those bits instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that helps. The question is whether Azure Websites can host Twisted applications like the above, which speak http directly, without requiring the needless creation of a WSGI app and losing all the benefits of async; or whether Azure Websites requires every Python site to be implemented in the form of a WSGI application, by which point you've missed out on the chance to handle anything at the http layer. If I misunderstand your suggestion, could you please provide some example code demonstrating running a Twisted app without having to create a WSGI app?